# How to overwrite an application package name during the installation in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

As per i know from my search knowledge, it is not possible to Overwrite an application package name during the application installation until we root our device. 
But still i'm looking for an unique way or ideas, there we can Overwrite the package name or uninstall the previous installed application by itself then reinstall the application. If any one can provide me an idea that will be so glad full. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible w/o root or adb connection ...

If you are looking for a way just for debugging, then you can just use adb uninstall command :

```
adb uninstall <package_name>
```

There is a way however, to uninstall the application through DELETE intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.getgoogleaccount"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

The app cannot delete itself and continue in any kind of flow that would reinstall it again, but I guess you could try to have 2 applications in the phone, where one would serve just as an installing manager that would schedule for a check if the app was uninstalled and resumed the installation process once the app was removed ..